# Typescript Datatable Array Type Exists?

Tags: typescript

I want a type in typescript but can not generate or initialize it.
It must be below format but I do not know name of this type or can not find resource to get experience using it.

```
        data: [
          ['Memory', 50],
          ['CPU', 99]
        ],
```

I saw a few usage, what is the name of this type and how to use it?

Comment: An array of tuples?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your array type to always have 2 items where first one is specific string and second is number.

```
type Types = 'Memory' | 'CPU';
type DatabaseType = [Types, number];

let a: DatabaseType = ["Memory", 30];

// not allowed
let b: DatabaseType = ["Something", 30];

// Not allowed more than 2 items in array
let c: DatabaseType = ["Memory", 30, 50, "Foo"];

let data: DatabaseType[] = [
  ["Memory", 50],
  ["CPU", 20]
]
```

Please see [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKpKBnGBeGByAslAtgewCcwMYAfTAYQAUBVDAblERgBEBDEdgI3aSgTQ0MANqDkAGhgA7AK65uUQgF0mwADZQQMdgC42nHnwEt0IgEQ4Cxc1IDMABlXBgAelcz829uvX4A7lAAJhpaMNz6HFy8-OLCFgDK+LhaABYAltIA5rYwjs5uHgByXjq+AcEw1rAgqezSMABMMOkgeCiZOoSE7GCh2gDGkYYxJkJmlnhEYLmOUgCsDlLmAGL4+OYFmtpBhsPRxuIiyvHAMKKT1jMLThJnFzS0uY1OwMpAA).